# linq select new and string

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ 
    class TestIO
    {  
        static void Main()
        {
            string line = "first-main-in-c#";

            var stringQuery = from ch in line where Char.IsDigit(ch) select new string(ch + '-');

            foreach (var c in stringQuery)
                Console.Write(c); 
            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to exit");

            Console.ReadKey();  
        }
    }
}
```

I am beginner in c# , what is my mistake, I expected this output:

```
f-i-r-s-t-m-a-i-n-i-n-c
```

but i get :

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,<>f__Anonymou
sType0`1[System.Int32]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Char.IsDigit determines whether the character is a decimal digit. There are no decimal digit characters in that string. You could use `Char.IsLetter` or `Char.IsLetterOrDigit`, depending on you want to include digits or not.

You are also calling a constructor on string that does not exist. You could use the one that takes a char array.

Finally, the query will return a sequence of strings. To get the desired result (one string as you stated), the code taking the above into account, could be:

```
string line = "first-main-in-c#";
var stringQuery = from ch in line where Char.IsLetter(ch) select new string(new char[] {ch, '-'});
string result = String.Join("", stringQuery);
```

This however will include a - at the end you will need to trim off. `String.Join` joins strings with a separator, so to get the result you want, this could be simpler:

```
string line = "first-main-in-c#";
var result = String.Join("-", from ch in line where Char.IsLetter(ch) select ch.ToString());
```

Comment: sorry but in my string `line`, `f` for instance is alphanumeric but `#` is not

Comment: The intent got a bit lost in terminology, please see updated answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to convert a character to a string is to use `ToString` on the character.

There is no overload of the `string` constructor that takes just one character, or a string.

You could use any of the following:

```
char c = 'a';

string s = c.ToString();
s = new string(c, 1);
s = new string(new[] { c });
s = c + "";
```

Since you adding two characters together you already have a string, so there's no need for `new string` in the first place:

```
var stringQuery = from ch in line
                  where Char.IsDigit(ch) 
                  select ch + '-';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var stringQuery = from ch in line where Char.IsLetter(ch) select ch + "-";
```

You will still need to trim off the last "-" to get the exact output you want.

I hope this helps